# Generate a web service client using cxf 3.0.2 runtime of wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to generate a web service client of this wsdl file:

```
http://soapclient.com/xml/soapresponder.wsdl
```

But I get this error:

```
WSDLToJava Error: Rpc/encoded wsdls are not supported with CXF

org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: Rpc/encoded wsdls are not supported with CXF
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.wsdl11.JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.checkSupported(JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.java:142)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.wsdl11.JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.build(JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.java:87)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.wsdl11.JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.build(JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:198)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:164)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:412)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.main(WSDLToJava.java:184)
```

Do you have any idea on how can I generate a web client for this wsdl in any other manner?

Answer (score 0):

RPC/encoded is not supported in CXF. If you want to generate a client for RPC/encoded then I recommend to use Apache Axis 1.4

https://axis.apache.org/axis/

More info regarding this can be found on this URL
http://architects.dzone.com/articles/wsdltojava-error-rpcencoded